# Sql Pivot Table how do i make it?

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, cube, rollup

Hi i want to ask something about my work

```
select * from 
  (Select m.Brand,u.Color,Count(Unit)as [Total unit] 
   from Brands m 
   inner join Products u on m.BrandID=u.ProductID 
   Group by m.Brand ,u.Color 
   with cube
   )as Pvt 
   PIVOT ( Sum([total unit]) 
   For Color IN ( [Black],[White],[Gray],[Silver],[Orange],[Dark Blue] ) 
   )AS Pivot_Table
```

I want to show total Brand and Total color but this code just calculate each color and count every color per brand

How can i get Total Brand and Total Color ?

Comment: can you post your table structures, some sample data and then the expected final result?

Comment: actually i solved problem but i want to get result total Color and Total Brands

Comment: Ok, but it would be easier to assist will more details, especially the table structure and sample data.